# Trying to set a state equal to data from axios fetch. Can console.log the data object but don't understand how to set to a state variable correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I have built a simple URL scraper that grabs Open Graph data from a url.
I am trying to save the data to a state variable so that I can render in a few different ways and maybe save it to a users profile. The app grabs the OpenGraph information successful and I can log this data object to the console. However, when I call setState(data) or setState({data}) the state does not update. I think it has something to do with the order of my function (when I try to update the state) but I am fairly new to React and I am not sure what I need to change.

Thanks in advance - code below:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function UrlCrawler() {
  const [openGraphData, setOpenGraphData] = useState();

  window.onload = () => {
    const urlForm = document.getElementById("urlForm");
    const url = document.getElementById("url");
    const result = document.getElementById("result");
    const copyToClipboard = document.getElementById("copyToClipboard");

    urlForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      axios({
        url: `http://localhost:3000/scrape`,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          url: url.value,
        },
      }).then(({ data }) => {
        setOpenGraphData(data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(openGraphData);
        copyToClipboard.classList.remove("invisible");
      });
    });

    copyToClipboard.addEventListener("click", () => {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(result.innerText);
      copyToClipboard.innerText = "Copied";
      setTimeout(() => {
        copyToClipboard.innerText = "Copy";
      }, 2000);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because `useState` hook is asynchronous, so if you log to the console the value of a state right after updating it, you'll see its previous value and not the updated one.

One thing you can do is use the `useEffect` hook to log the state every time its value changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(openGraphData)
}, [openGraphData])
```

By putting your state inside the dependencies array, the function inside this `useEffect` will execute every time it updates.

Comment: Yes thank you this is exactly what I was missing!